# can we use hasPermission secution expression in xml config of spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

Could we use something like this in spring configuration xml file :

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >

        <intercept-url pattern="/hardcopy/*" access="isAuthenticated() and hasPermission('tw')" />
    </http>
```

Look above at the code and line where it says hasPermission in access attribute. Could it be used like that?

Also related to this question :
[How to get hold of user details in custom expression handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566118/how-to-get-hold-of-user-details-in-custom-expression-handlers)

When I am trying to use it this way I am getting this error:

```
500 Unexpected error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'isAuthenticated() and hasPermission('tw')'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'isAuthenticated() and hasPermission('tw')' at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:13) at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:34) at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18) at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62) at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at no.nhst.escenic.publication.servlet.PublicationResolverFilter.doFilter(PublicationResolverFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:554) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 22): Method call: Method hasPermission(java.lang.String) cannot be found on org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot type at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:273) at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:251) at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:194) at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:134) at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getBooleanValue(OpAnd.java:51) at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpAnd.getValueInternal(OpAnd.java:46) at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102) at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98) at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11) ... 59 more
```

PLease any suggestions with the error?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not getting back on this earlier. Try splitting the expression up and see which one is causing the error. My guess is that it is hasPermission since it is not in the documentation which I posted in the answer. Try hasRole('tw') instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to check if the user `isAuthenticated()` it is enough to check for the respective user role. because without being authenticated the user wouldn't have any grantedAuthorities in the securitycontext.
   Also it is enough to just list the roles like this:

```
access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"
```

Edit:

To come back to this. Technicaly what you wanted to do is not wrong. You can use the methods and also chain them together. This link provides all expressions Spring security has built in for that purpose: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html
  If you use own methods i don't know how it is handled since I haven't felt the need to look into it.

Comment: Oh that is a good point, so does that mean that I cant use hasPermission() in access attribute? In general I mean.

Comment: I have tried using that, but I am getting an error, I will update my question with the error I am getting when using hasPermission in intercept-url in a bit.